# Table starts new line after a space in th and td

Tags: html, css

I have this table that is very long:

```
<table>
<tr>
<th>testtest test</th>
<th>zxcccccccxacasdwqeqw wqeewqeqe</th>
<th>testtetwtwewadwad wdadwad wdadwad twetewtetw etwtewtw</th>  
<th>testtetwtwetwetewtetw etwtewtw</th>
<th>testtetwtwetwetewtetw etwtewtw</th>
<th>testtetwtwetwetewtetw etwtewtw</th>
<th>testtetwtwetwetewtetw etwtewtw</th>
<th>testtetwtwetwetewtetw etwtewtw</th>
<th>testtetwtwetwetewtetw etwtewtw</th>
<th>testtetwtwetwetewtetw etwtewtw</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>test test</td>
<td>daw dawdawd awd awd awd awd</td>
<td>d wadwaeqeeqw ewqeqwewq eqw</td>
<td>d wadwaeqeeqw ewqeqwewq eqw</td>
<td>d wadwaeqeeqw ewqeqwewq eqw</td>
<td>d wadwaeqeeqw ewqeqwewq eqw</td>
<td>d wadwaeqeeqw ewqeqwewq eqw</td>
<td>d wadwaeqeeqw ewqeqwewq eqw</td>
<td>d wadwaeqeeqw ewqeqwewq eqw</td>
<td>d wadwaeqeeqw ewqeqwewq eqw</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Now this creates for every table header a standard height of 4 lines because the longest sample text has 4 spaces. I dont want this to happen. I dont want it to create a new line with every space it has. How would I accomplish this?

This also happens for the td but only creates 2 spaces. Probably because the words aren't long enough in the longest one to create new lines for those.

Comment: Apart from styles (`overflow: hidden`) you could use the `<nobr>` tag. Or you could use `&nbsp;` (non-breaking spaces)

Comment: @Burki nobr seems to work but I dont think this is a clean way of doing it. Also I want it on multiple tables.

Comment: I assume you cannot influence the content of your table header or table cells. In this case i would go ith stylesheets, specifying a width and height and setting overflow: hidden.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use nowrap attribute for a particular th, td if you want to do that for a particular cell(s) - not supported in HTML5, done through CSS.

If you want to apply it to all cells then you can use the CSS. ie:

```
<html>
<head>
 <style>
th, td { white-space: nowrap;}
 </style>
</head>
 <body>
  <table>
<tr>
<th>testtest test</th>
<th>zxcccccccxacasdwqeqw wqeewqeqe</th>
<th>testtetwtwewadwad wdadwad wdadwad twetewtetw etwtewtw</th>  
<th>testtetwtwetwetewtetw etwtewtw</th>
<th>testtetwtwetwetewtetw etwtewtw</th>
<th>testtetwtwetwetewtetw etwtewtw</th>
<th>testtetwtwetwetewtetw etwtewtw</th>
<th>testtetwtwetwetewtetw etwtewtw</th>
<th>testtetwtwetwetewtetw etwtewtw</th>
<th>testtetwtwetwetewtetw etwtewtw</th>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>test test</td>
<td>daw dawdawd awd awd awd awd</td>
<td>d wadwaeqeeqw ewqeqwewq eqw</td>
<td>d wadwaeqeeqw ewqeqwewq eqw</td>
<td>d wadwaeqeeqw ewqeqwewq eqw</td>
<td>d wadwaeqeeqw ewqeqwewq eqw</td>
<td>d wadwaeqeeqw ewqeqwewq eqw</td>
<td>d wadwaeqeeqw ewqeqwewq eqw</td>
<td>d wadwaeqeeqw ewqeqwewq eqw</td>
<td>d wadwaeqeeqw ewqeqwewq eqw</td>
</tr>
</table>
 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I was just about to answer this to my own question. Like literally I was writing it then this answer showed up. +1